# Bridged Ubuntu guest on VMWare Player not accessible via TCP from host only

Tags: networking, vmware-player

Using VMWare Player 3.1.3 build-324285 on Windows 7 64 bits, guest is Ubuntu 10.10 with VMWare tools installed. For networking, the Ubuntu guest is bridged.

Here is the problem :
 - ICMP work from my Windows host to the Ubuntu guest.
 - TCP works from any host on the network to the Ubuntu guest BUT my host.
 - Any other PC can access to the apache server on port 80, but from my Windows host I get a request timeout when triying to see the page.

Any idea ?

PS : I don't want to use NAT and I need the guest to be accessible from me and from anyone on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem with a Mac Host and Ubuntu Guest this evening.

I suspect this might have something to do with ubuntu updates, but I can't prove it.

I fixed my mac install by deleting the existing network device, adding a new one, resetting the mac address (advanced) and specifically selecting the network adapter rather than "auto detect". A reboot later and it was back.

Unfortunately this doesn't explain why it happened which i've not been able to determine but it might get you up and running again at the very least.

Comment: I have no option auto detect for network adapter.  
You mean you just spoofed the virtual mac after an ubuntu update and it worked back ?

Comment: The auto detect may be a red herring. The point was, I deleted the existing network interface, and created a new one, that seemed to satisfy the guest OS or spur it into action to reconfigure and recognise it.